# How to detect Force Close on Mac OS X app

Tags: swift, macos, event-handling

I have a Mac OS X app and I want to detect or catch the event when the user Force Close my app.

At first I thought `applicationWillTerminate` will do the work but it didn't:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    print("applicationWillTerminate called")
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** I'm not an expert, and researching for this post has stretched the limits of my rusty C/Objective-C knowledge. I don't know how the following code is viewed by Apple for submissions to the App Store, so YMMV.

The [following has been shamelessly ripped from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling#Example_usage) and reworked:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/**
 This will handle signals for us, specifically SIGTERM.
 */
void handleSignal(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGTERM) {
        // Caught a SIGTERM
    }

    /*
      SIGTERM is a clear directive to quit, so we exit
      and return the signal number for us to inspect if we desire.
      We can actually omit the exit(), and everything
      will still build normally.

      If you Force Quit the application, it will still eventually
      exit, suggesting a follow-up SIGKILL is sent.
    */
    exit(sig);
}

/**
 This will let us set a handler for a specific signal (SIGTERM in this case)
 */
void setHandler() {
    if (signal(SIGTERM, handleSignal) == SIG_ERR) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to set a signal handler.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully set a signal handler.");
    }
}
```

> **Call only asynchronous-safe functions within signal handlers.** [See here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers).

You could place the above in a C/Objective-C file and use it in Swift via a [Bridging Header](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). Call `setHandler()` somewhere in the beginning of your application's lifecycle, e.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, and you should now have a chance to do some work before your app is Force Quit. I don't know how much time you get here, so I'd keep the workload as light as possible (avoid starting mission-critical stuff here, I guess?).

---

Here's some background info:

#### In a typical Quit

The Quit procedure is actually a part of [Apple Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/apple_event_manager).

> - If the application is `NSDocument`-based, the behavior depends on the saving parameter, which has one of these three values:
>
>   - *`NSSaveOptionsNo`*: The application quits without sending a close message to any document.
>   - *`NSSaveOptionsYes`*: Each unmodified document is sent a close message; each modified document is sent the following message:
>       `saveDocumentWithDelegate:didSaveSelector:contextInfo:`
>   - *`NSSaveOptionsAsk`*: (This is the default value if no saving parameter is supplied in the event.) If there are modified documents
>       open, the `NSDocumentController` sends itself this message:
>       `reviewUnsavedDocumentsWithAlertTitle:cancellable:delegate:didReviewAllSelector:contextInfo:`
> - If the application is not `NSDocument`-based, the application delegate is sent this message (if it is implemented):
>     `applicationShouldTerminate:`
>
> You can modify the default behavior by implementing this method.
>
> *Source*: [How Cocoa Applications Handle Apple Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-1121178)

#### During Force Quit

The application is sent a [`SIGTERM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGTERM) which can be caught and dealt with by your application. Ideally, the application would clean up and exit as gracefully as possible, but this isn't required, and the signal can even be ignored.

An impatient user (and I *strongly **suspect*** that `Force Quit` does this eventually) may send a [`SIGKILL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGKILL), which cannot be ignored and totally goes over anything you as the developer can stop.

---

#### Extra Information and Resources:

[What does Force Quit do in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53762)

[What signals does OS X send for the Quit and Force Quit commands?](https://superuser.com/a/481317)

[How Cocoa Applications Handle Apple Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239)

[SIGTERM vs. SIGKILL - major.io](https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/)

[C Signal Handling - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling)

Comment: Awesome answer - going to follow up some with details

Answer (score 4):

Major credit goes to @caseynolan for putting work in here to come up with an answer. Unfortunately, there are, in fact, some major issues with the suggested approach.

First, signal handlers are **per-process**. There are other, legitimate uses of signals, and installing handlers will negatively impact their behavior without very careful work.

Second, signals interrupt a thread, and that thread can be doing anything, including holding locks. Examples of things that hold locks - malloc/free, the Objective-C runtime.

This is an part of a class of problems known as "async safety". If you check out "man sigaction" (note, `sigaction` is a much improved API over `signal`) you see that there are actually a very small number of functions that are safe to call from a signal handler. Calling unsafe functions, like `NSLog`, will sometimes work. But, will also sometimes deadlock, depending on what the thread was doing at the time.

Now, I will admit that my experience with signals does not include use of `SIGTERM`. However, since it can be delivered at any time, it still will be subject to async safety issues, even thought it is not a crash.

In short: it is almost certainly unsafe to run your code in a signal handler, and it will deadlock sometimes. And, those deadlocks will occur during unpredictable points of its execution.

Third, there are fatal events that aren't mapped to signals, on top of SIGKILL. This may not matter to do, depending on how strong a guarantee you need about detecting your process termination.

### What I'd do Instead:

I think you're only safe option is to use a **sentinel process**. The idea is you start up a child process, and in that child, observe the parent. If/when that process disappears, you can then execute your code.

This is a safe, deadlock-risk free way to monitor for arbitrary process exits. However, it could be challenging to move your operations out-of-process. Unfortunately, I believe that's a necessary aspect of this, if you want it to be reliable.

Good luck!

Comment: With the sentinel process, any idea how to detect if the parent process was force quit or not? I'm trying to distinguish between the parent crashes, closed normally, or force quit (note that a force quit might happen when the app in not responsive which is easier to detect, but might also be for no reason at all). Would be good to also "detect" if the parent was killed with a SIGKILL.

In other words, any way to figure out if the parent received a SIGTERM or SIGKILL?